# SOIL Unhandled exception at 0x585727FF

Tags: c++, visual-studio, soil

I have an error I don't know how to solve.

I created a simple program, using VS2012, in order to test SOIL (sample code from SOIL's website):

```
#include "SOIL.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <glew.h>
#include <freeglut.h>

int main() {
std::cout << "Started" << std::endl;

/* load an image file directly as a new OpenGL texture */
GLuint tex_2d = SOIL_load_OGL_texture
    (
    "img.png",
    SOIL_LOAD_AUTO,
    SOIL_CREATE_NEW_ID,
    SOIL_FLAG_MIPMAPS | SOIL_FLAG_INVERT_Y | SOIL_FLAG_NTSC_SAFE_RGB | SOIL_FLAG_COMPRESS_TO_DXT
    );

/* check for an error during the load process */
if( 0 == tex_2d )
{
    printf( "SOIL loading error: '%s'\n", SOIL_last_result() );
}
}
```

I get the error:

```
Unhandled exception at 0x585727FF (msvcr110d.dll) in imageLib.exe: 0xC0000005: Access violation reading location 0x00000000.
```

Any help is appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: Turn on 'break when exception is thrown' (in the debug/exceptions menu from memory) and you can get the stack trace, which should provide more info.

Comment: Just step through the code. Breakpoints should take you to the line where the issue happens exactly..

Comment: Thank you for your reply. Ok I think I turned it on. Is this the stack trace?
https://docs.google.com/file/d/0B36QIOj3F-a3TzRVVEE3blNYYjg/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: @Attaque: seems soil failed to get the gl ext strings, this generally happens if you use OGL before creating a context on the thread.

Comment: Thank you Necrolis. I included the piece of code in another project, and it worked as expected.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All I did was to make sure GL was loaded before trying to use a GLuint as Necrolis suggested.

If you have the library loaded correct, this small example should run without errors (does not display anything, but shows the order of GL and SOIL:

```
#include "SOIL.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <glew.h>
#include <freeglut.h>

#define WINDOW_WIDTH  800
#define WINDOW_HEIGHT 600

void LoadTexture() {
/* load an image file directly as a new OpenGL texture */
GLuint tex_2d = SOIL_load_OGL_texture
    (
    "Data/img.png",
    SOIL_LOAD_AUTO,
    SOIL_CREATE_NEW_ID,
    SOIL_FLAG_MIPMAPS | SOIL_FLAG_INVERT_Y | SOIL_FLAG_NTSC_SAFE_RGB | SOIL_FLAG_COMPRESS_TO_DXT
    );

/* check for an error during the load process */
if( 0 == tex_2d )
{
    printf( "SOIL loading error: '%s'\n", SOIL_last_result() );
}

// Typical Texture Generation Using Data From The Bitmap
glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, tex_2d);
glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D,GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER,GL_LINEAR);
glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D,GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER,GL_LINEAR);
}

int main(int argc, char** argv) {
std::cout << "Started" << std::endl;

glutInit(&argc, argv);
glutInitDisplayMode(GLUT_DOUBLE|GLUT_RGBA);
glutInitWindowSize(WINDOW_WIDTH, WINDOW_HEIGHT);
glutInitWindowPosition(100, 100);
glutCreateWindow("Tutorial 15");

glutSwapBuffers();

LoadTexture();

glEnable(GL_TEXTURE_2D);                            // Enable Texture Mapping ( NEW )
glClearColor(0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f);

glutMainLoop();

return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I have faced with these issue so many times. I think this is caused by absence of error handling SOIL library.

when loading your image data ,the path  may be incorrect. In my cases, I write the path like in that form;

```
C:/Users/User/Pictures/texture.JPG
```

but when I change this path like that, there is no error when building the project ;)

```
file:///C:/Users/User/Pictures/texture.JPG
```